# My iCloud icon has disappeared and I can't log in to verify my Apple ID

Tags: iphone, icloud

I can't verify my email Apple ID, but it's my Apple ID and I have never changed it.

[image]

Comment: What iCloud icon are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking to make sure that your email is correct. I have unintentionally messed up my email, it happens.

Other than that, log on to a PC and try logging in to your email.